# Lizmap and custom themes

Tags: css, lizmap, theme

I can't find where to change the footer_logo in Lizamp, through a custom theme.

I downloaded the default theme with the command `mydomainname.com/index.php/view/media/getDefaultTheme`. Then I just changed the `logo.png` and the `footer_logo.png` and put all the files in the media directory.

But when I reload my website, I only have the `logo.png` that is updated.

Where and how can I change the footer?

Answer (score 0):

you probably don't see it because you need to clear the cache.
I did and the logo was replaced.

Comment: Indeed, try a "CTRL+R" on Firefox (or similar on other webbrowser) to "hard refresh" (without the cache).

Comment: Logo yes, but not the footer...